# How to set level meter on sound recording in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio-recording

For recording sound, I am using the following code:

```
- (IBAction) recordClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"play Record");
    if (audioPlayerRecord) {
        if (audioPlayerRecord.isPlaying) [audioPlayerRecord stop];
        else {
            [audioPlayerRecord play];
            [self updateCurrentTimeForPlayer:audioPlayerRecord];
        }
        return;
    } 

    //Initialize playback audio session
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *recDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/recordTest.caf", recDir]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayerRecord = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    [audioPlayerRecord play];
    duration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", (int)audioPlayerRecord.duration / 60, (int)audioPlayerRecord.duration % 60, nil];
    progressBar.maximumValue = audioPlayerRecord.duration;
    [self updateViewForPlayerState:audioPlayerRecord];
    NSLog(@"Recoder file >");
}
```

When recording is on going , I want to show the following type of level meter

[image: Level meter]

So is there any other simplified way to achieve this problem?

Comment: the `SpeakHere` is the perfect example how you can use the `AvFoundation` and `AudioToolBox` frameworks... yes, it takes some extra days to understand it, but I assume you are not lazy to learn new techniques. :)

Comment: Hello PDP have you solved your problem me too facing the same please help ASAP...

Answer (score 0):

check AQRecorder.mm ...

find: `void AQRecorder::StartRecord(CFStringRef inRecordFile)`

here you must comment / remove de line

```
url = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)recordFile, NULL);
```

with

```
url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)recordFile, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
```